# SQL Query to Get Values between characters in string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL field that stores HTML such as this:

```
Table: Template
Fields: NotificationId (int), Template (varchar(max))
```

Example row:
NotificationId 1, Template
The template field contains HTML in this form:

```
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr><td>{RESULTFLD:0:customer_name}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{RESULTFLD:1:customer_address1}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{RESULTFLD:2:customer_address2}</td></tr>
</body>
</table>
```

What I need to do is parse this somehow where I want to get if possible the NotificationId then a list of each field name in the HTML.  For example:

NotificationId 1, then each field name with a line break if possible
customer_name
customer_address1
customer_address2

Tricky part seems to be the number of the result field increments so trying to parse this HTML to get those values.

Thanks for any help if this seems doable.

Comment: Doable, maybe. Practical no - HTML parsing is tricky on its own. It has enough quirks that you can't treat it as XML nor can you use regular expressions to parse all cases. And SQL Server doesn't have regular expressions at all. You may be able to use XML functions BUT the snippet you posted i malformed (</table> comes after</body>)

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to fill an HTML template with data, why do you want to parse the template with SQL? It's infinitely easier to use an HTML parser on a client language or, better yet, the template library that's meant to handle this text

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: The data shown is really (X)HTML, so it is easy to process it via XQuery.

Comment: Does this template come from an existing system? Or is this an attempt to create a new template engine? In the latter case, it's a lot better to use an existing popular template engine like [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) or its equivalent in C#, [Scriban](https://github.com/scriban/scriban). Jinja is so popular you can find VS Code extensions and linters for it. It's used in a *lot* of tools, including dbt

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky it's not - `</body>` and `</table>` are out of order, making this invalid XML. Browsers will still render it. If this was a Jinja template, VS Code's [Better Jinja](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samuelcolvin.jinjahtml) would have caught the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query which should achieve your requirement. As noted in the comments, however, just because you can it does not mean you should. Doing this in SQL is always going to be hacky.

```
CREATE TABLE htmldata ( NotificationId int, Template varchar(max))

INSERT INTO htmldata VALUES (1, '<body>
<table border="1">
<tr><td>{RESULTFLD:0:customer_name}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{RESULTFLD:1:customer_address1}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{RESULTFLD:2:customer_address2}</td></tr>
</body>
</table>')

DECLARE @NotificationId INT;
DECLARE @Template NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @StartPosition INT;
DECLARE @EndPosition INT;
DECLARE @FieldName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE (NotificationId INT, FieldName NVARCHAR(MAX));

-- Create a cursor to iterate through the rows
DECLARE template_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT NotificationId, Template
FROM htmldata;

OPEN template_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM template_cursor INTO @NotificationId, @Template;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @StartPosition = CHARINDEX('{RESULTFLD:0:', @Template);
    
    WHILE @StartPosition > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @EndPosition = CHARINDEX('}', @Template, @StartPosition);
        
        IF @EndPosition > 0
        BEGIN
            -- Extract the field name between {RESULTFLD:<n>: and }
            SET @FieldName = SUBSTRING(@Template, @StartPosition + 13, @EndPosition - @StartPosition - 13) + ' ';
            
            -- Insert the result into the result table
            INSERT INTO @ResultTable (NotificationId, FieldName)
            VALUES (@NotificationId, @FieldName);
            
            -- Move to the next occurrence
            SET @StartPosition = CHARINDEX('{RESULTFLD:', @Template, @EndPosition);
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- If no closing '}' found, exit the loop
            BREAK;
        END
    END
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM template_cursor INTO @NotificationId, @Template;
END

CLOSE template_cursor;
DEALLOCATE template_cursor;

-- Retrieve the results
SELECT CONCAT(NotificationId, ' ', STRING_AGG(FieldName, '')) AS NotificationAndFieldNames
FROM @ResultTable
GROUP BY NotificationId;
```

Comment: This worked perfect thanks.  I know not practical at all working with what I got to deal with and this was a big help with the parse thank you all.